# Editing an animated GIF

Tags: image, photoshop, editing, gif

I'd like to *edit* an *animated* gif to change its background from white to #f5f5f5:

[image]

Photoshop can import it and shows as layers, but saves only the first frame. Are there any editors, preferably online tools that allows it?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: you'd be better off using a graphic with a transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Graphics Gale](http://www.humanbalance.net/gale/us/index.html) is used by a lot of pixel art guys, it is rather good for working with animated GIFs.